# On click events app crashed after navigation of a segue when receiving push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, uistoryboard

My application is almost completed, now i'm working on push notifications. I able to receive push notifications successfully, unfortunately i'm not able to perform segue in Appdelegate. Basically i have two base screens 1.login 2.Tabbar controller i'm handling this in app delegate as shown below.

```
UIStoryboard* appStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

if (![self connect])
{
    UINavigationController *home=[appStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginScreen"];
    self.window.rootViewController=home;
}
else
{
    //TabbarHome
    UITabBarController *home=[appStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabbarHome"];
    //pushNotificationSeague

    self.window.rootViewController=home;
}
```

when i receive a notification i tried to push using Storyboard ID like

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
NotificationViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyNotification"];
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window]addSubview:controller.view];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Now navigation is done. But the Click event are making app to crash. Reason i found is the below line, without this line of code app will not navigate. If we i use the below code the allocation of memory issue is there i guess.

```
 [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window]addSubview:controller.view];
```

Please help me with fixing issue. Why the actions in the NotificationViewController are making crash. crash report is

```
 [NotificationViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7ffdc60a8890
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not add addSubview to window.

It is not making sense that you are pushing the viewController and also you are adding it to window subview. Just remove the following line

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window]addSubview:controller.view];
```

Finally it should be

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
NotificationViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyNotification"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: push is not happening. I guess we need to do with segue identifier. Because the other view controller already loaded

Comment: Check the navigationController object is not nil. If not get the navigationController object from window rootviewcontroller